# Can ubuntu be installed using a networked drive?

Tags: installation

My laptop doesn't allow booting from USB and the CD drive has gone bad. It has Windows XP on it. I want to do away with Windows and use Ubuntu only.

Comment: you might be able to use unetbootin to bootstrap an install instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your laptop doesn't allow booting from USB?

You may need to enable *legacy USB support* in the BIOS setup to enable it, then reboot with the bootable USB in the drive, then go into BIOS setup a second time and select the boot devices, looking for the removable drive.

Otherwise, you may have success installing using [WUBI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide), by running the WUBI installer from within Windows.  Note that this will install to a small partition within Windows, rather than replacing Windows.